# Nant and changing file properties (read-only to writable)

Tags: nant

As part of the Nant copy task, I would like to change the properties of the files in the target location. For instance make the files "read-write" from "read-only". How would I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the <[attrib](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/tasks/attrib.html)> task. For example, to make the file "test.txt" read/write, you would use

```
<attrib file="test.txt" readonly="false"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Also, for a list of files, the command is:

```
<attrib readonly="false">
  <fileset basedir="mydirectory">
    <include name="**"/>
  </fileset>
</attrib>
```